# Error 1004 with match method in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, match

I'm working in two different sheets in excel, each which have a set of about 1200 ID numbers. When referencing sheet 1 (RG Summary), I'm trying to find which row number the ID shows up on sheet 2 (Purchasing Matrix). This is to ultimately do some conditional formatting on sheet 1, where the sheet 2 IDs have specific values on their row. I really know very little about VBA (I'm just doing a side job for my internship this summer), so I'm sure I could be missing some major concept... But currently I get this error

*Run-time error '1004:
Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class*

on

```
RowNum= WorksheetFunction.Match(ID2, Range("E10:E1500"), 0)
```

When debugging, I can see that the ID2 is carrying the ID value of the first iteration, but RowNum returns as 0.

```
Sub DisplayMatrix()

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, ItemID As String, rng1 As Range, _
ID2 As String, RowNum As Integer, PM As Worksheet

'initiates loop in sheet 1
'each ID is 7 cells apart
 For i = 14 To 1757 Step 7

        'sets ID variable where ID is present
        If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then ItemID = Worksheets("RG Summary").Cells(i, 2).Value

          'finds ID in sheet2
           ID2 = Worksheets("Purchasing Matrix").Cells.Find(What:=ItemID, _
           LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
           SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

          'matches ID2 and ItemID and returns row number from sheet 2
           Set PM = Worksheets("Purchasing Matrix")
             With PM
             RowNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(ID2, Range("E10:E1500"), 0)
             End With


  Next i
  End

End Sub
```

Comment: Try substituting "Application" for "WorksheetFunction" as the object which contains the match function. I'm on linux right now so I can't verify that's the problem but that would be my first guess. The docs at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835873.aspx are a bit ambiguous as to how this should be used but it appears that the example uses Match() as a method of Application.

Comment: The error "type mismatch" returns when I do that!

Comment: Give me a moment to pull up windows and I'll take another look.

Comment: What line does the error occur on?  Also, perhaps try adding `.Value` to the end of the `Find()` when you set `ID2 = ...`

Comment: I think what is happening is excel is matching data types as well as the contents of the cell. Is it possible to format your entire workbook as text?

Comment: @BruceWayne the error is on 'Rownum=...' because I'm assuming it is not finding a match

Comment: Yes, match isn't a finding a match because column E most likely has mixed data types. Run text to columns on column E with a delimiter that you know doesn't exist in the column and use Text as the data type. That should solve your problem.

Comment: To debug, replace what you have with whatever you expect `ID2` to be. Say you're looking for the string `Manor`, do this: `ID2 = Worksheets("Purchasing Matrix").Cells.Find(What:="Manor",LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Value` and see if `ID2` correctly gets set to "Manor". If not, we have other issues.

Comment: @hobenkr it works now thank you :-)

Comment: @hobenkr actually what I noticed was that the code only works whenever my sheet named "Purchasing Matrix" is open. Do you know why that is the case?

Comment: I find a good practice is to run `Worksheets("My worksheet name").Activate()` whenever you want a piece of code to apply to a specific worksheet. For example, insert `Worksheets("Purchasing Matrix").Activate()` before the line where you assign to the variable `ID2`.

Comment: The `RowNum` is only being used with that worksheet, see your `With PM` line.  My personal feeling is to avoid using `.Activate`, and instead never use simply `Cells()`, but instead `Worksheets("mySheet").Cells()`...  So, where you also have `Cells(i, 2).Value`, put the sheet of whatever value you want in front - so like `Worksheets("Purchasing Matrix").Cells(i, 2).Value`

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
RowNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(ID2, Range("E10:E1500"), 0)
```

with:

```
RowNum = WorksheetFunction.Match(ID2, .Range("E10:E1500"), 0)
```

*(the dot may be small, but it is important)*
*(there may be other problems)*